# Weird behaviour in random.choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to randomly reorder an Array using my `scramble` function:

```
def scramble(arr):
    arr_len = len(arr)
    container = [None]*arr_len
    indexes = [i for i in range(arr_len)]
    print(random.choice(indexes))       # works as expected
    for i in range(arr_len):
        my_choice = None
        while not my_choice:
            my_choice = random.choice(indexes)
            print(my_choice)        # always None
            if my_choice is not None:
                indexes[my_choice] = None
                container[my_choice] = arr[my_choice]
    print(container)

scramble([2,3,4,5,6])
```

The issue that I'm facing is that `my_choice` variable is always containing `None`. Can anyone please point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function?

Comment: Tangential, but: `indexes = list(range(arr_len))`…

Comment: If you want to implement your own shuffling algorithm, at least implement [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

Comment: @deceze can you please point out that why doing `print(my_choice)` always prints `None`?

Comment: Are you sure `print(my_choice)` gives `# always None`?

Comment: It doesn't *always* print `None`, only after a couple of iterations, when you have replaced all items in `indexes` with `None`.

Comment: @deceze Ok. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the above code is in the line `while not my_choice:`. Remember, that `my_choice` variable can contain both 0 and `None` (both of those values are falsy).

So, I'd recommend changing your code to something like this (if you don't want to use `random.shuffle`):

```
def scramble(arr):
    arr_len = len(arr)
    container = [None]*arr_len
    indexes = [i for i in range(arr_len)]
    # print(random.choice(indexes))       # works as expected
    for i in range(arr_len):
        # print("i is {}".format(i))
        my_choice = None
        # while not my_choice:
        while my_choice is None:
            my_choice = random.choice(indexes)
            print(my_choice)        # always None
            if my_choice is not None:
                indexes[my_choice] = None
                container[i] = arr[my_choice]
    print(container)

scramble([2,3,4,5,6])
```

Also, do `container[i] = arr[my_choice]` instead of `container[my_choice] = arr[my_choice]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are setting `indexes[my_choice]` to be None, as result at some point all elements in the `indexes` list is `None`, and the while loop becomes never ending.

To scramble the list you can  use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function from standard library:

```
import random

arr = [2,3,4,5,6]
random.shuffle(arr)
print arr
```

Comment: Simply removing that line would probably lead to the wrong outcome. That line is supposed to avoid picking duplicates.

Comment: In a single while loop I'm setting indexes[my_choice] to be None, just once. Also, while condition is inside for loop which runs only 5 times

Comment: Technically correct, but not really helpful. Why doesn't the loop end after all indices have been set to `None`? There's a `for i in range(arr_len):` loop at the top, and in every iteration that loop sets one index to `None`. So after all indices have been set to `None`, why does the loop keep going?

Comment: Why do you shuffle `indexes` instead of `random.shuffle(arr)` directly…?!

Comment: While the code does indeed no longer enter an infinite loop, it's still nothing more than a no-op. It doesn't scramble the input list at all. Here's a one-liner that does the same thing: `def scramble(arr): print(arr)`

Comment: @Aran-Fey See the question.

Comment: @deceze following code in the question, added notes about manipulating arr directly.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko What's your point? The OP said they want to scramble a list, and your code doesn't do that.